# What's the Fedora equivalent of /var/lib/dpkg/info/[...].prerm?

Tags: debian, shell-script, fedora, scripting, maintenance

Example file:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/util-linux.prerm
```

What's the Fedora equivalent of this file? (Not limited to util-linux - generic question for any package.)

Use case: A prerm script is failing. For debugging purposes, I would like to enable xtrace (`sh -x`).

Answer (score 4):

Fedora uses RPMs. Assuming the util-linux RPM is installed on your system, the command to show the pre-removal scriptlet is:

```
rpm -q --queryformat '%{PREUN}\n' util-linux
```

You can check if the "util-linx" RPM is installed with this command:

```
rpm -q util-linux
```

If you want to show all RPM scriptlets for util-linux, you can use this command:

```
rpm -q --scripts util-linux
```

EDIT: Since the pre-removal script failed, it is possible that the RPM did not get installed. In this case, you can view the scriptlet of an uninstalled RPM with this command:

```
rpm -qp --scripts util-linux
```

To view all scriptlets for every package that is currently installed on your system:

```
rpm -qa --scripts
```

Comment: But how do I run the scriptlet with debugging enabled? (xtrace, `set -x`)